# Has many through associations with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a condition to a has many through association without luck. This is the association in my video model:

```
has_many :voted_users, :through => :video_votes, :source => :user
```

I want to only get the `voted_users` whose video_votes have a `value` equal to 1 for that video. How would I do this?

Comment: Is `votes` an association or is it a field name?

Comment: does 'whose votes have a value equal to 1.' mean the same as 'who have only voted once' ?

Comment: Adam, yeah I think we are hoping to also see the: has_many :video_votes

Comment: sorry... by `votes` I meant `video_votes`, `value` is a field in the video_votes table

Comment: and I do have `has_many :video_votes`

Comment: Yeah I guessed that `:video_votes` was actually it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a model method within the video model class
Something like:

```
def users_with_one_vote
  self.voted_users, :conditions => ['value = ?', 1]
end
```

Then in the controller use `video.users_with_one_vote`

Then testing is easier too.

Any chance you can change that column name from 'value'.  Might give some issues (reserved?).

Comment: Would this work, considering `value` is a field in the video_votes table, not the user table...

Comment: I don't think value is reserved... value represents whether it is an upvote or a downvote

Comment: This won't work (I think). Don't you need to have some sort of query there like `self.voted_users.all(:conditions => "video_votes.value = '1'")` ?

Comment: for the .all, maybe.  But I believe just using the plural model name may work as rails uses the convention of plural for all.  I think I have conditions right though?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in 2 stages:

First, I'd define the `has_many :through` relationship between the models without any conditions.

Second, I'd add a 'scope' that defines a where condition.

Specifically, I'd do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_votes
  has_many :votes, :through=>:video_votes
  def self.voted_users
    self.video_votes.voted
  end
end

class VideoVote
  def self.voted
    where("value = ?", 1)
  end
end

class Video
  has_many :video_votes
  has_many :users, :through=>:video_votes
end
```

Then you could get the users that have voted using:

```
VideoVote.voted.collect(&:user).uniq
```

which I believe would return an array of all users who had voted. This isn't the exact code you'd use -- they're just snippets -- but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
has_many :voted_users, :through => :video_votes, :source => :user, :conditions => ['users.votes = ?', 1]
```

Do the trick?

Comment: no, I don't think putting that condition on the base join is a good idea.

Comment: Care to share more? I can't say I agree, although I don't understand why it would be a bad idea.

Comment: I think that the base join as shown is the one that should always be there regardless of that 'count' which would be better handled by a model method.

Comment: @Michael: I don't see how this is a bad idea or why it was downvoted.

Comment: Ryan - because, as other posters have noted, it's combining two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I found that defining this method in my model works:

```
def upvoted_users
  self.voted_users.where("value = 1")
end
```

and then calling `@video.upvoted_users` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this without messing with the relations is by crafting a more complex query. Relations is not the best thing to use for this particular problem. Please understand that relations is more a "way of data definition" then a way of "bussiness rules definition".

Bussiness logic or bussiness rules must be defined on a more specifically layer.

My suggestion for your problem is to create a method to search for users who voted on your video only once. something like:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  def voted_once()
    User.joins(:video_votes).where("video_votes.value == 1 AND video_votes.video_id == ?", this.id)
  end
```

Rails is magical for many things, but complex queries still have to be done in a "SQL" way of thinking. Don't let the illusional object oriented metaphor blind you

Answer (score 0):

As long as we are throwing around ideas, how about using association extensions.

```
class VideoVote
  scope :upvotes, where(:value => 1)
end

class Video
  has_many :voted_users, :through => :video_votes, :source => :user do
    def upvoted
      scoped & VideoVote.upvotes
    end
  end
end
```

Then you feel good about making a call with absolutely no arguments AND you technically didn't add another method to your Video model (it's on the association, right?)

```
@video.voted_users.upvoted
```